# Cookies Not Returned by ReactTs Frontend to Springboot backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, cors

I have a reactTS+vite+mantine frontend and a Springboot backend. The setup are below.
When I try to create sessions with the use of cookies, I cannot seem to get the frontend to return the cookies.
(Also, if someone knows how to get cross origin Spring Sessions working please contact me.)

#### Login function (Supplies a sessionID)

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<User> loginUser(
            @RequestParam(value = "rmbr", defaultValue = "false") boolean rememberMe,
            @RequestBody User user
    ) {
        UserDatabase userDatabase = new UserDatabase();

        User returnUser = userDatabase.getUserByUsernameOrEmail(user);

        if (returnUser.getUsername() == null || returnUser.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(returnUser, HttpStatusCode.valueOf(462));
        }
        if (BCrypt.checkpw(user.getPassword(), returnUser.getPassword())) {
            returnUser.setPassword(null);
            UUID sessionId = UUID.randomUUID();
            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,"SESSIONID=" + userDatabase.createCookie(sessionId.toString(), user, rememberMe));


            return ResponseEntity
                    .ok()
                    .headers(responseHeaders)
                    .body(returnUser);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new User(), HttpStatusCode.valueOf(463));
    }
```

I did try to use the

```
HttpServletResponse response
```

route and creating a cookie object and I got the same problem.

#### get Details function for retrieving session details

```
@GetMapping("/details")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserFromSession(
            @CookieValue("SESSIONID") String sessionId
    ) {
        UserDatabase userDatabase = new UserDatabase();
        User user = userDatabase.getCookieUser(sessionId);
        user.setPassword(null);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new User(), HttpStatusCode.valueOf(200));
    }
```

When this request is made the console prints out the following:

```
2023-12-09T11:41:59.960+02:00  WARN 19748 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestCookieException: Required cookie 'SESSIONID' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

#### Login function for the frontend

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
        const user: User = {
            email: (/^\S+@\S+$/.test(form.values.email) ? form.values.email : ''),
            username: (/^\S+@\S+$/.test(form.values.email) ? '' : form.values.email),
            password: form.values.password,
            profilePhoto: '',
            bio: '',
            role: 'user',
            orgName: ''
        };
        try {
            const response = await fetch( serverIp + 'user/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(user),
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                login(await response.json())
                closeModal()
            } else if (response.status == 462) {
                setErrorMessage('User Does not Exist');
            } else if (response.status == 463) {
                setErrorMessage('Invalid Password');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setErrorMessage('Could not connect to server, Please check internet connection')
            console.error('login fetch error', error)
        } finally {
            close()
        }

    }
```

#### Get details setup for web loading

```
const fetchUserDetails = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${serverIp}user/details`, {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: 'include',
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const user = await response.json();
                login(user); // Update user details on successful API response
            } else {
                console.error('No active sessions found for this device');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching user details:', error);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserDetails();
    }, []);
```

#### Spring Security Temp Config

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true); // Allow credentials (e.g., cookies)
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*")); // Allow requests from this origin
        config.addAllowedHeader("*"); // Allow all headers
        config.addAllowedMethod("*"); // Allow all HTTP methods
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

### More details

I tried enabling all cookies, I also tried different ip's like localhost and 127.0.0.1
I also made cookies with hosts and http only set to true and false,

It works on postman, but not in the browser

Thank you for your time

#### I have tried

- Enabling all cookies in browser
- used spring cookie and httpservletresponse
- works in postman
- http only = true
- http only = false
- http only not set
- maxage at -1
- max age at 8 hours
- setting the domain
- setting the path
- different urls like localhost and 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I got The solution, you need to allow-credentials for the requests that has the incoming cookie